# How to pass dynamic value in request body in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing on chatbots using jmeter. I need to pass dynamic session id for each request, please let me know the possibility.

Customized request body:

{
        "botName": "***********",
        "sessionId": "*************",
        "conversationId": "*************",
        "messageId": "************",
        "cognitiveService": "luis",
        "channel": "**********",
        "message": "***********",
        "callbackUrl": "****************",
        "userId":"***************"
 }

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line:

```
"sessionId": "*************",
```

with the reference to a [JMeter Variable or Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so JMeter will substitute the placeholder in the runtime.

For example if you use the following construction assuming [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID):

```
"sessionId": "${__UUID}",
```

JMeter will use a unique [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) structure for each virtual user/iteration.

More information: [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/)